# Mock current location for android testing

Tags: android, android-testing

Is there a way to mock the current location on an android device for testing without using another mock location provider app?
I have a navigation app that I need to do some instrumentation tests on and the UI is dependent on the current tracked position. When I tried to grant permission access for mocking location it threw the error:
 `Permission: android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION cannot be granted!`

this is my code.

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class SpeedTTSWarningTrackingInstrumentedTests
{
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private var lm : LocationManager? = null
companion object
{
    private val appContext: Context = getApplicationContext()
    private val mainIntent = Intent(appContext, MainActivity::class.java)
    private var mActivityIdlingResource: IdlingResource? = null
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Rule(order = 0)
@JvmField
val permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    Manifest.permission.INTERNET,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION,
    "android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
)


@Rule(order = 1)
@JvmField
val activityScenarioRule = ActivityScenarioRule<MainActivity>(mainIntent)

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@Before
fun beforeTests(){
    activityScenarioRule.scenario.moveToState(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)
    runBlocking { delay(2000) }
    activityScenarioRule.scenario.onActivity { activity ->
        mActivityIdlingResource = activity.getActivityIdlingResource()
        IdlingRegistry.getInstance().register(mActivityIdlingResource)
    }
}

@After
fun closeActivity(){
    activityScenarioRule.scenario.close()
}
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


@Test
fun changeLocation(){
    runBlocking { delay(10000) }
    mockLocation(45.661936, 25.608026)
    runBlocking { delay(10000) }
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
private fun mockLocation(lat: Double, lon: Double)
{
    lm = getSystemService(appContext,LocationManager::class.java)
    val mocLocationProvider = LocationManager.FUSED_PROVIDER

    lm!!.addTestProvider(
        mocLocationProvider, false, false,
        false, false, true, true, true, 3, 2
    )

    lm!!.setTestProviderEnabled(mocLocationProvider, true)

    val mockLocation = Location(mocLocationProvider) // a string

    mockLocation.latitude = lat // double
    mockLocation.longitude = lon
    mockLocation.time = System.currentTimeMillis()
    mockLocation.accuracy = 1f
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    {
        mockLocation.elapsedRealtimeNanos = SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos()
    }
    lm!!.setTestProviderLocation(mocLocationProvider, mockLocation)
}
}
```

P.S I am new to testing in general. I am looking for some guidance. Is there something I am doing wrong? How would you approach this problem?
I just found out that *android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION* has been removed as of API level 23. Any ideas on what I could do now?

I tried using a mock Location Provider and GrantPermissionRule. I also created a specific debug AndroidManifest.

Is this the right approach?

Comment: You can change the emulator location from emulator settings. that might help you with testing

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the app for simulated locations in the settings:
Go to `Settings` and select the `More Settings` tab. Click on `About Phone` and then press the `Software Version` tab a few times unless you get a pop-up about the developer option being enabled. Now open the `Developer Options` tab and find `Select Mock Location App`. Open the tab and select the app for a mock location.

Comment: " testing without using another mock location provider app"